# How to preserve the default button appearance behavior when binding EVT_LEFT_DOWN

Tags: wxpython

I have a button in wxpython for which I have bound `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` and `EVT_LEFT_UP`.  I need to know explicitly when it is pressed and released, that's why I'm not using `EVT_BUTTON`.

The events work fine, the problem is just aesthetic: when I bind `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` and `EVT_LEFT_UP` the button no longer exhibits the normal appearance of being pressed (shaded and indented).

Is there any way to explicitly know when a button is pressed and released but also preserve its default appearance behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for this.

If I call `event.Skip()` in my handlers for `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` and `EVT_LEFT_UP` it seems to propagate the event such that the default button appearance behavior is restored.